# Является ли паттерн Строитель в Java примером реализации Монады?

Tags: java

Возник вопрос после чтения этой статьи: https://habrahabr.ru/company/cit/blog/262055/

Является ли паттерн "Строитель" в Java примером реализации "Монады"?

```
Student s = new Student.Builder()
                .name("Vasya")
                .age(18)
                .language(Arrays.asList("chinese","english"))
                .build();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если коротко, то нет.

Давайте разберемся, что является монадой ?  Это такая структура данных у которой есть две операции `pure` и `bind`:

`pure(v)` - получение монады для значения `v`

`bind(f)` - выполнение функции `f`, принимающей в качестве аргумента значение монады. возвращает новую монаду.

Для данной структуры должны выполняться следующие правила:

1. Левая индентичность

   > `pure(v).bind(f) = pure(f(v))`  применение операции `bind` на монаде эквивалентно созданию монады из значения функции `f` с аргументом  `v`
2. Правая идентичность

   > `pure(v).bind(Monade::pure) = pure(v)` применение операции `bind` с функцией `pure` на любую монаду эквивалентно этой же монаде.
3. ассоциативность

   > `pure(v).bind(f).bind(g) = pure(v).bind(g(f(v)))` последовательное применение операций `bind` с функциями `f` и `g` на любую монаду идентично применению операции `bind` с композицией этих функций на эту монаду.

Теперь, если взглянуть на паттерн строитель с точки зрения этих правил, то увидем, что у него нет операций, удовлетворящих данным правилам.

Comment: java-стримы тоже не являются монадами?

Comment: Нет, не является. Если методом pure считать Stream.of а методом bind Stream.map - все правила выполняются, кроме второго. т.к. если в метод Stream.of положить другой стрим, то он вернет стрим стримов, что не правильно.

Comment: вот _настоящие_ законы монад, с учетом имен методов Stream: 1) `Stream.of(v).flatMap(f) ≡ f(v)`, 2) `stream.flatMap(Stream::of) ≡ stream`, 3) `stream.flatMap(f).flatMap(g) ≡ stream.flatMap(v -> f(v).flatMap(g))` и `Stream` им не противоречит